# What is the difference between Observable and Flowable in RxJava 2.0?

Tags: java, rx-java

Observable and Flowable interfaces seem to be identical. Why Flowable was introduced in RxJava 2.0? When should I prefer to use Flowable over Observable?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0

Comment: Backpressure support.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ajay.dewari/backpressure-in-reactivex-rxjava-and-difference-between-observable-and-flowable-6074c25234ea

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable):

> A small regret about introducing backpressure in RxJava 0.x is that
>   instead of having a separate base reactive class, the Observable
>   itself was retrofitted. The main issue with backpressure is that many
>   hot sources, such as UI events, can't be reasonably backpressured and
>   cause unexpected `MissingBackpressureException` (i.e., beginners don't
>   expect them).
>
> We try to remedy this situation in 2.x by having
>   `io.reactivex.Observable` non-backpressured and the new
>   `io.reactivex.Flowable` be the backpressure-enabled base reactive class.

Use `Observable` when you have relatively few items over time (<1000) and/or there's **no risk** of producer overflooding consumers and thus causing OOM.

Use `Flowable` when you have relatively large amount of items and you need to carefully control how `Producer` behaves in order to to avoid resource exhaustion and/or congestion.

---

**Backpressure**
When you have an observable which emits items so fast that consumer can’t keep up with the flow leading to the existence of emitted but unconsumed items.

How unconsumed items, which are emitted by observables but not consumed by subscribers, are managed and controlled is what backpressure strategy deals with.

[Ref link](https://medium.com/@srinuraop/rxjava-backpressure-3376130e76c1)

Comment: I would think they should still support a common interface, or Flowable should extend Observable, that way they can be merged and such

Comment: https://medium.com/@ajay.dewari/backpressure-in-reactivex-rxjava-and-difference-between-observable-and-flowable-6074c25234ea