# What are the actual advantages of Observable over Flowable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

[What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable) describes the differences between `Observable` and `Flowable`.  However, `Observable` is mostly described in terms of features that it lacks in comparison to `Flowable`.  There is only one distinguishing feature of `Observable` mentioned:

> Using `Observable` has lower overhead in general than `Flowable`.

But even this seems to be contradicted by the suggestion that `Observable` is preferable for small numbers of elements and is more likely to lead to an `OutOfMemoryError` if tasked too heavily.  This seems to suggest that `Flowable` is generally more efficient.

The other thing I find confusing is that if `Observable` is preferred for use cases with fewer than 1K elements, and `Flowable` is preferred for use cases with over 10K elements, then use cases having between 1K and 10K elements are a gray area.

**Is there a more technical explanation of the differences between `Observable` and `Flowable`?**  Especially one that suggests a practical heuristic for deciding which to use in the gray area between 1K and 10K elements, or when the number of elements is unknown or may change.

Related: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947649/what-is-the-difference-between-observable-and-flowable-in-rxjava-2-0) only quotes the documentation without further explanation.

Comment: It looks like _the_ distinguishing feature is whether backpressure is enabled or not. By gut instinct I'd use the backpressured variant if possible, but I'm not into this topic...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a more technical explanation of the differences between Observable and Flowable?

I'll give you one but most people get scared by the technical details.

> However, Observable is mostly described in terms of features that it lacks in comparison to Flowable.

Yes, because technically `Observable` is `Flowable` minus the backpressure related request coordination logic on all of its operators.

> But even this seems to be contradicted by the suggestion ...

There is no contradiction, getting values through an `Observable` from one end to the other encounters less "resistance" because the logic doesn't have to deal with request coordination or temporary buffering. For example, `Observable.flatMapIterable` doesn't have to queue up source items because each inner `Iterable` can be streamed in its entirety immediately from the `onNext`. `Flowable` has to queue items, trampoline the draining and Iterable item emission and limit it to the requested amount in a fairly expensive queue-drain logic compared to a straight emission.

> This seems to suggest that Flowable is generally more efficient.

There is a tradeoff between memory usage (thus GC overhead) and latency.

> Then use cases having between 1K and 10K elements are a gray area.

It means that between the two numbers, you may need to find other decision variables, such as individual element size, expected latency, what's the rest of your app/system doing, etc.

> or when the number of elements is unknown or may change

The case for `Observable` uses the word "longest", that means at any given time, you have a possibly buffered sequence of 1000 elements or less, or alternatively, your source emits at most 1 element per millisecond on average.

This is otherwise a typical "depends" case:

- Can the source be reasonably backpressured?
- Is the processing logic generally slower than the source or its upper stages?
- Do different subscribers encounter different number of elements?
- Is the environment constrained in some way?
- Are the items relatively large?

If you can answer with yes to these questions, you are better off with `Flowable`.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable` and `Flowable` are very similar. `Flowable` is newer and generally more advanced:

- it implements *backpressure*
- it conforms to Java [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) specification (to be included in JDK9)

The reason `Observable` still exists is conceptual compatibility with original Microsoft's ReactiveX framework. Remember RxJava is part of [ReactiveX project](http://reactivex.io).

I would suggest `Flowable` over `Observable` in most (or even all) cases. Unless you are working on multi-language project where Java part is non-dominant.