# What is the resources consuming when Observable switched to Flowable

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2, vert.x, backpressure

We are switching project from javaRx 1.x to javaRx 2.x. i cant really understand:

1. Why i should keep Observable in my project instead of using
   Flowable everywhere.
2. If i know the place there is no any back pressure do i need to
   use Flowable with no back pressure setup (default,
   ON_OVERFLOW_ERROR) does it make difference with new javaRx 2.x
   Observable in term of memory, processor time use?
3. Will i have more potential errors if i keep Observable?

Here we have some explications: [What is the difference between Observable and Flowable in RxJava 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947649/what-is-the-difference-between-observable-and-flowable-in-rxjava-2-0)

What is the difference if i use everywhere Flowable?

Comment: Under the section "Observable and Flowable" of the documentation at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0 explains well the difference and when to use what. What part of it do you not understand ?

Comment: The question is : if i use Flowable instead of Observable even if i have less then 1000 elements (as explained there ) what will be the disadvantages of that. In other words i am misusing Flowable with Observable. Do we have more  processors time working, or memory consuming in case of Flowable. If we dont why we distinct it - i can use everywhere only Flowable and why Observable isn't obsolete. Thanks a lot for explication.